# Find all integers $(x;y)$ satisfy $y^2+2y=4x^2y+8x+7$

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $(x;y)$ satisfy $y^2+2y=4x^2y+8x+7$

Here's my way of solving it, but got stuck midway.

From the equation we can find $x$ using quadratic formula:

$$x=\frac {-2\pm\sqrt{y^3+2y^2-7y+4}}{2y}.$$

But $x$ is an integer, thus $y^3+2y^2-7y+4$ must be a perfect square. That also means:

$$y^3+2y^2-7y+4=(y-1)^2(y+4)$$

is a perfect square.

**Case 1:** $y-1=0 \iff y=1 \Rightarrow x=-1$.

**Case 2:** $y+4$ is a perfect square.

And then... I'm stuck. I used Wolfram Alpha and found out that the equation has finite integer solutions. Is there any way to further figure out the solutions? Or is there any other way for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance. Much obliged.

Comment: $y = a^2 - 4$? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second case, setting $y=a^2-4$ yields
$$
x=\frac{a^2 - 2a - 1}{2(a - 2)},
$$
or
$$
x=\frac{-a^2 - 2a + 1}{2(a + 2)},
$$
Writing this as $x=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2(a-2)}$ etc., we see that the only solutions are $a=-3,-1,1,3$ with $x=1$.

Comment: Can you further explain the $x=\frac {a}{2} - \frac {1}{2(a-2)}$ part?

Comment: This part shows that we cannot obtain an integer for all $a\neq 1,3$, because the second term then is not an integer or half integer.